# Определить, на каком этаже находится квартира

Tags: c#, олимпиада

Дано количество квартир (n), подъездов (p), этажей (q) и сам номер квартиры (k). Определить, на каком этаже и в каком подъезде находится заданная квартира под номером k.

Немного пояснений:
n - это количество квартир, т. е. квартир во всем доме. n - сумма кол-ва квартир во всех подъездах.

Потому и даются подъезды - неизвестно, сколько квартир в 1 подъезде. На пример вводятся такие данные: 18 3 3 16. Здесь этажей 3, подъездов 3, а в каждом p находятся по 6 квартир.

Вот данные примера в виде таблицы:

1,2   7,8   13,14

3,4   9,10  15,16

5,6   11,12 17,18

Ответом в данном примере будут числа 3 и 2. 3 подъезд, 2 этаж. Думаю, я прояснил. По крайней мере, как я понимаю данную задачу: https://clck.ru/NcmBu

Вот моя попытка. Подъезд определяет вроде всегда правильно, а вот с этажами проблема - никак не получается. Пробовал обычным перебором - не вышло:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public class CSharpSrudy2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str1 = Console.ReadLine();
            int[] arr = str1.Split(' ').Select(w => Convert.ToInt32(w)).ToArray();
            int n = arr[0], p = arr[1], q = arr[2], k = arr[3];
            int pod = 0, et = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int y = n / p;
            int x = y / q;
            if (k <= y)
            {
                pod = 1;
                while (i <= y)
                {
                    if (k <= i)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    et++;
                    i += x;
                }
            }
            if (k > y)
            {
                while (k > y)
                {
                    pod++;
                    y *= 2;
                }
                pod++;
            }
            y = n / p;
            if (k > y)
            {
                for (i = ((pod - 1) * y) + 1; i < pod * y; i += x)
                {
                    if (k < i)
                    {
                        if (k == i)
                        {
                            et++;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    et++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(pod + " " + et);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Циклы вам не нужны, задача решается за константное время

Comment: @АндрейNOP, если количество квартир на этаже одинаковое :)

Comment: @Grundy, а оно одинаковое и есть. В исходных данных всегда задано ровно 4 числа

Comment: Очень интересно про константное время: я так понимаю, можно формулы какие-то вывести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На этаже находятся `s = n / (p * q)` квартир.

В одном подъезде `sp = n / p` квартир.

Номер подъезда `np = 1 + (k - 1) / sp`

Номер этажа `ne = 1 + ((k - 1) % sp) / s`

Деление целочисленное.

Проверяем на 30 2 5 27:

```
s = 3
sp = 15
np = 1 + 26/15 = 2
ne = 1 + (26 % 15) / 3 = 1 + 11/3 = 4
```

Проверяем на 18 3 3 16:

```
s = 2
sp = 6
np = 1 + 15/6 = 3
ne = 1 + (15 % 6) / 2 = 1 + 3/2 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Квартиры `1..n*q` расположены в первом подъезде, `n*q+1..2*n*q` во втором и т. д. Как этим воспользоваться? С помощью целочисленного деления:
`a = (k-1) / (n*q) + 1`
Минус единица и плюс единица здесь из-за того, что нумерация идёт с 1, а не с 0.
Далее, номер квартиры в подъезде, тоже самое, но надо брать остаток от деления, а не частное:
`b = (k-1) % (n*q) + 1`
По аналогии определяем этаж:
`c = (b-1) / n + 1`
Номер квартиры на этаже:
`d = (b-1) % n + 1`
Непонятно для чего задано число подъездов p, может быть для проверки граничных условий или может быть несколько домов?

Comment: Немного прояснил в основной части вопроса. Посмотрите выше - начиная со слов "Немного пояснений..."

Comment: Ok, вы можете перейти от тех чисел, что заданы, к тем, что используются у меня. А потом использовать мои формулы. Всё.

Comment: Либо я тупой, либо формулы не подходят. Я бьюсь уже несколько вечеров, а на ум приходят только решения циклами, да и те проходят только на 60%: https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/126

Comment: Либо же я неправильно использую формулы(